# Google SDTT Sitelinks Search - Invalid syntax for the urlTemplate

Tags: google-search, schema.org

We have an online shopping website and I recently implemented a search engine for our items in the shop. I would like to implement a Google Sitelinks Search Box for our SERP.

By using this markup

```html
<div class="search-wrap">
  <form class="search-form" action="https://zadomaigradinata.bg/продукти.php" method="get" itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
    <meta itemprop="target" content="https://zadomaigradinata.bg/продукти.php?search-input={search-input}&action=search-items"/>
    <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search-input" value="" placeholder="Търсете в Магазина">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="search-items"></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and marking up only the homepage of my site like this

```html
<body class="index" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://zadomaigradinata.bg/"/>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Магазин За Дома И Градината"/>
```

After reading a bit about this method of implementation I have found that the `target` and the `url` values need to be of the same domain (as it is here).

I have also tried to use only Latin symbols and avoid Cyrillic, but the SDTT gives me this error:

> `urlTemplate`
>   `https://zadomaigradinata.bg/продукти.php?search-input={search-input}&action=search-items` (There is an error in your Sitelinks Search Box template: INVALID_SYNTAX.)

Considering that the name for the input field is the same as used in the template in brackets `{search-input}` and that the link has been tested to work by replacing the `{search-input}` with any other text, I cannot think of any other reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDTT doesn’t seem to like the `-` in your `{search-input}`.

If you replace it with `_`, no error gets reported:

```html
<meta itemprop="target" content="https://zadomaigradinata.bg/продукти.php?search-input={search_input}&action=search-items"/>
<input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search_input" value="" placeholder="Търсете в Магазина">
```

Comment: My lord you are right, changing that dash to an underscore cleared all the errors. Thank you my friend ! Accepted answer